# How can I make the values from Field 1 the column headers and the values from Field 2 the values associated with the new Field headers?

Tags: python

I have a .csv file that has 2 fields.  How can I make the values from one of the fields the column headers and the values from the other field the values associated with the column headers?

Field Header 1 is currently named: Attributes, Field Header 2 is currently named: Values. I want to flip this around so that the values in the Attribute field are now the Field Headers and the values in the Value field become the values associated with each header.

Thanks.

[.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUbMa.png)

Comment: Is this a python question or an excel question? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it’s a python question. I found the answer by using the transpose function.

Thanks